# Can I send value from javascript to angular controller at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For example, I have HTML that will show only in the popup

```
<div id="popup1" style="display: none; width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
<div ng-controller="DataBindingCtrl">



    <div rel="title">
        Show or Update Image
    </div>
    <div rel="body" style="padding: 10px; line-height: 150%">
        <div >
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg" style="float: left; background-color: white; width: 250px; height: 320px; border: 1px solid silver; margin: 5px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="w2ui-field w2ui-span3">
            <label>Files:</label>
            <div>
                <form class ="form-horizontal">
                    <input id="file" style="width: 100px" />{{selBookId}}
                    <input id="currentRecord" type="text" ng-model="currentRecordText" ng-model-instant> 
                    {{currentRecordText}} {{idRec}}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div rel="buttons">
        <button class="btn" onclick="$('#popup2').w2popup()">Switch to Popup 2</button>
    </div>*@
</div>
```

I want to set a value for **idRec** when the user clicks on the popup window button.

Is this possible and what is the proper way ?

Comment: I guess you can have a hidden text field whose `ng-model` is pointing to `idRec`

Comment: Whenever you need to use jQuery with Angular it's best to put the jQuery stuff in a directive. Then you'll be able to pass whatever parameters you want from the view to the directive and use them with your jQuery code.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: you can use $emit and $on with parameters to update a controller (or controllers) after the action on form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you want to change the scope variable from jQuery function.

You can use jQuery function in your Angular controller as below.

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $('.popupCall').on('click', function(){
        $scope.idRec= "newValue";
        $scope.$apply();
        $('#popup2').w2popup();
    });
}

<button class="btn popupCall">Switch to Popup 2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you - you are right, you give me a proper way !

Comment: But - as I understand there is no way for send data inside angularjs controller. We need intercept events from controller body without any variants ...

Comment: If you want to call and pass value to Angular function from a jquery event you can do this with angular.element try and google it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a function to your controller on the scope.

DataBindingCtrl

```
$scope.idRec = '';
$scope.updateIdRec = function() {
     $scope.idRec= "newValue";       
     $('#popup2').w2popup();
};
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="updateIdRec()">Switch to Popup 2</button>
```